# iPhone: Splash screen in app - Good or Bad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I'm going to submit a Lifestyle app to the App Store. I'm confused **whether to add a Splash Screen to the App or not** ?

Please advise me whether it's a good or bad idea as far as usability and App Store's submission guidelines are concerned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely at least add a Default.png to your app if I understand your question correctly.

Launching an app and looking at a black screen for a split second is not the best user experience. Some nice-looking image with your company name or app logo will do. Or you could follow Apple's guidelines and present an image of the starting user interface so that your app will seem to load instantly.

Here's a relevant [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW12).

Comment: Default.png will be displayed until you return from `applicationDidFinishLoading:` method. If your app loads blazingly fast, you could make a UIImageView which would display the same image for as long as you like before actually showing the real user interface of the app. The transition from Default.png to your interface will be seamless.

Comment: if your app loads blazingly fast, it would be better just to display the UI and have done with it.

Comment: @JeremyP I agree. It's not my app though, the true author has the right to choose.

Answer (score 3):

Its bad - you shouldn't do that!
Please read the Start Instantly Section of the Apple HI Guidelines

> Avoid displaying an About window or a
>   splash screen. In general, try to
>   avoid providing any type of startup
>   experience that prevents people from
>   using your application immediately.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html

Answer (score 2):

The developers guides mostly suggest a splash that looks like the starting screen of your app, to give people the impression the app has started. This has the bonus of allowing the user to start figuring out what they want to do while the program finishes loading.

From a users standpoint, I dislike most splash screens, I just want to get to the program, not look *once again* at what constitutes an advertisement for the program.

Answer (score 1):

if your app loads blazingly fast,then you can provide this method in

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application 

[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3];
```

Before your view controller is loaded.

It will halt the main thread for 3 seconds,which will give time to your splash screen.Thats the way i do and there is no problem with this method,as you are working on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add a splash screen to your app.

Depending on what you do with your splash screen as far as extravagant animations go, I would go subtle, with minimal animations.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I've read somewhere on the web that some of the apps got rejected because of splash screen. And that apps were not having any animations and extravagant graphics.

Comment: I have used splash screens in many apps that I have in the iTunes AppStore. I even have one that fades the default image into the app, so it really depends on how what you do with your splash screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `Default.png` (see iOS documentation!) to your application bundle.
This image is being shown full screen while your application is loading.

Other than that, I wouldn't add a splash screen to your app.

Comment: Apple hasn't accept such submissions in the past - the Default.png should show an picture of your UI/titlescreen!

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So is it a wise idea to have a Launch Image rather than create a splash screen using UIView ? Example(1st Image): http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/amazon-deals/id404217731?mt=8#